# Convert my Xcode application to a webapp (to use tabbar)

Tags: javascript, xcode, ipad, web-applications, tabbar

I have made a basic tabbar view app in xcode but I need it to be a webapp as I will be viewing the data from a server so do not need/ want it on the app store.

I've looked at some other questions with this kind of topic and nothing is relevant. Also I've done plenty of googling and looking into other code plus using things like cubiq.org's slide-in menu.

I really want that tabbar look. I've tried to do this in HTML with images as buttons and using frames but (I think) because I'm using the JS code to stop the UIview from moving (to look more native) it seems that the buttons open the link in a new page, or switch to Safari, rather then open them in the same frame as they would in a regular browser.

Alternatively, does anyone know of a way I can implement a taskbar in a webapp?

Regards,

Eric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) !?

It's awesome... but still in Beta.

They have precisely the toolbar you're looking for: [JQuery Mobile Navbar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)

Comment: I think I just found my new favorite tool!

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's hard to pinpoint your problem exactly, but you should not be doing:

```
<a href="link_to_some_resource">Text of Button</a>
```

Because the above code will actually load a different page. Rather, you want:

```
<div class="some_button_type" onclick="doSomeAction()"><!-- ... --></div>
```

And that "doSomeAction()" function should use DOM manipulation to transform the *current* page to look like whatever you want it to look like (rather than navigating to some separate page).

P.S. I'm assuming you have some CSS styling based on class type, and you might want content in the DIV (for example, for the text of the button). I've also omitted some  attributes (e.g. "role") that you want.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I will be sure to implement this! :)